# Why i need to use Base64 in this encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption, base64

I see encryption in java.In that to generate secret key they have

```
 KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
 Key secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

 byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getEncoded()
 Key secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

 byte[] key = secretKey.getEncoded();

 byte[] encodedKey=Base64.encodeBase64(key );

 String keyText = new String(encodedKey);
```

My question is why what is the need of using  `Base64.encodeBase64(key)`. What is the problem if i use directly

```
String keyText = new String(key);
```

I am confusing.Please help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: "I am confusing." Indeeed... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every sequence of bytes represents a valid `String`: [you need to know the character encoding in order to interpret a sequence of bytes as a string](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Since Java's `char` is 16-bit, a random sequence of bytes can end up representing a string with invalid code points in it. Using the Base-64 encoding fixes this problem by ensuring that all elements are valid characters from `[A-Za-z0-9+/]` range.

Comment: can i ask another question

Comment: can you see here i posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119632/how-securerandom-is-working-injava