# How SecureRandom.getInstance() is working in Java

Tags: java, security, encryption

Here i am using

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("here my name") ;
```

But it is not giving any exception in our project.But when i run using main method it is giving `NoSuchAlgorithm Exception`  exception for me.Also it is working fine for me.What it the reason.I am in confusion?

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("here my name");
```

But here i am getting exception why?Please help me .Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does `SecureRandom` give you a non-null, valid object? [It crashes for me](http://ideone.com/Srcxtw).

Comment: yes it is giving valid object for me

Comment: i used that one  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,random); here

Comment: What names do you get when you call `Security.getProviders()`? Is `"here my name"` string among them? According to the documentation, you cannot pass anything outside of `Security.getProviders()` list of names, otherwise you get an exception.

Comment: i did not used Security.getProviders() any where.What is this

Comment: It's [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProviders()), it lets you find all registered security providers available in your system, [like this](http://ideone.com/r7ep75).

Comment: i am getting SUN
SunRsaSign
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
SunMSCAPI

Comment: i am using a key which is not in this list

Comment: Then `SecureRandom` should have thrown a `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, as stated in their [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)).

Comment: no it is working fine for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28555/discussion-between-dasblinkenlight-and-psr)

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you can pass a string to `SecureRandom.getInstance` and get a valid result does not guarantee that passing the same string to `KeyGenerator.getInstance` would also be successful.

To find out what algorithms are supported on your system, [run this code](http://ideone.com/ry62ei), and look at the results:

```
for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {
    for (Object o : p.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

The output will contain lines that look like this:

```
Cipher.AES
KeyGenerator.RC2
Mac.HmacSHA512
...
SecureRandom.NativePRNG
SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG
...
KeyGenerator.DES
KeyGenerator.DESede
```

The names prefixed with `"SecureRandom."` (i.e. `"NativePRNG"`, '"SHA1PRNG"') can be passed to `SecureRandom.getInstance`, while the names prefixed with `"KeyGenerator."` (i.e. `"RC2"`, `"DES"`, `"DESede"`) can be passed to `KeyGenerator.getInstance`.

Comment: but here i am able to passing my name for secure random.I am confusing please help me

Comment: @PSR This behavior does not comply with the method documentation: the doc [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)) that it is supposed to "Throw
`NoSuchAlgorithmException` if no Provider supports a SecureRandomSpi implementation for the specified algorithm."

Comment: sorry if i am giving trouble to you.We are using this and is working.So i am in confusion

Comment: @PSR I would try stepping through it in the debugger then: stepping through JDK's source code should be allowed. Also try printing the result of `random.getAlgorithm()` and see what it gives you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28569/discussion-between-dasblinkenlight-and-psr)